# how to show trackballBehavior by default to some value when SfCartesianChart graph load in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show last value of my list data at SfCartesianChart Line series.i have used trackballBehavior.show in initState() method to show some value but it didn't work.

in my code i have display simple chart but i want to display some value of my list should be display default when graph is loaded

This is my code below

```
class ChartWithTrackball extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChartWithTrackballState createState() => _ChartWithTrackballState();
}
class _ChartWithTrackballState extends State<ChartWithTrackball> 
  bool showTrackball = false;
  SalesData? lastDataPoint;
  final GlobalKey<SfCartesianChartState> _chartKey = GlobalKey<SfCartesianChartState>();
  // Sample data for demonstration
  List<SalesData> chartData = [
    SalesData(1, 20),
    SalesData(2, 35),
    SalesData(3, 25),
    SalesData(4, 45),
    SalesData(5, 30),
  ];
  late SfCartesianChart chart;
  late TrackballBehavior  trackballBehavior;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    trackballBehavior = TrackballBehavior(

        enable: true,
        shouldAlwaysShow: true,
        markerSettings: TrackballMarkerSettings(
        markerVisibility: TrackballVisibilityMode.visible,
    ),
    lineType: TrackballLineType.vertical,
    activationMode: ActivationMode.longPress,
    tooltipAlignment: ChartAlignment.near,
    tooltipDisplayMode: TrackballDisplayMode.groupAllPoints,
    tooltipSettings: InteractiveTooltip(
    format: 'Point: #pointIndex\nValue: #point.y',
    ));
    print(chartData.last.year);
    print(chartData.last.sales);
    trackballBehavior.show(chartData.last.year, chartData.last.sales,"pixel");

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(showTrackball);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Chart with Trackball')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SfCartesianChart(
              key: _chartKey ,
              primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(),
              series: <LineSeries<SalesData, num>>[
                LineSeries<SalesData, num>(
                  dataSource: chartData,
                  xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.year,
                  yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales,
                  enableTooltip: true,
                ),
              ],

              trackballBehavior: trackballBehavior,

            ),
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}

class SalesData {
  final num year;
  final double sales;

  SalesData(this.year, this.sales);
}
```